# Common file-formats for writing research papers

Tags: publications, journals

This is a rewrite of a question that was perhaps-naively posed. I rephrase...

What file formats are ok/good/ideal/common/long-term-viable/archivable/useful for research papers?

And, also, there's the history-question:

What is the story of viable file-formats in the last 20+ years?

Comment: File formats for *what?* Data? Papers? Lab notebooks? This question to me sounds akin to asking, "I need to buy a storage container for my... stuff. Can you recommend me a common, archivable, useful one?" It completely depends on the purpose.

Comment: Formats for writing, or for reading?

Comment: "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." - voting to close

Comment: I work in a medical research department and its all .pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**plain text/markup language**

For mathematics, I think TeX/LaTeX is the way to go.  This is the standard way to write papers in nearly all areas of math (perhaps not biomath, where collaborators necessitate Word), so there's little extra cost.  One advantage of this approach is that it's easy to automate outputting in almost any format you want.  Furthermore, as new formats develop, we will almost certainly develop tools to convert TeX source to these new formats.  The arXiv is a great example of this model.

Answer (score 6):

Many people know what I'll say here, but I thought the re-format of the situation was appropriate...

For mathematics and "hard" sciences, PDF (portable document format) is absolutely standard now. Until a few years ago, PS (postscript) and DVI (device independent) formats were typical, but no more.

In mathematics, "Word" format was never common.

Currently, traditional (meaning various things) mathematics journals want a PDF file to send to referees. Everyone has software that can convert PostScript files to PDF, and so on. In fact, "OpenOffice", for example, can convert/export "Word" files to PDF.

So, in sciences, PDF, though "Word" may be forgivable.

The question of future readability of these or any other file formats is hugely non-trivial. (Similarly, kids-these-days, such as my almost-20 daughter, have great difficulty reading "cursive writing" of "old" people. :)

So: modulo issues that the original questioner can't afford to worry about, the current answer is "PDF, and tolerance for Word files, esp. from the humanities...".

The long-term answer about survivable file-formats... is troubling. :)

Answer (score 1):

binary/plain text

Other things to consider (for the future) is the movement towards standard meta-data items contained with the research articles (e.g. structured abstracts, specific research repositories, meta-analyses), and supplemental material for reproducible analysis. These suggest to me the conversation should likely include more than one data file.

IMO we can be more imaginative than word or pdf files. For instance open access journals frequently have everything right there in html on the page. I even think this idea [for a fast journal](http://yihui.name/en/2012/03/a-really-fast-statistics-journal/) by Yihui Xie using markdown for revisions and compiling to html is a good idea.

This is forward thinking though. Realistic constraints force collaborations to work with WYSIWYG file formats and PDF *for writing* because such behavior has not permeated enough in many fields (although for exceptions in some fields that extensively write in Latex see Jeffe's comment below). That may change in the future though, especially if journals adapt submission standards that encourage such actions.

Comment: _Obviously realistic constraints force collaborations to work with WYSIWYG file formats_ — Unless you're a mathematician, physicist, computer scientist, or somebody else who uses latex.

Comment: @JeffE, sure and I didn't really intend that statement to be taken as deterministic about *everyone* in academia. I have updated to make this clear. That being said though, outside of those few fields which use latex extensively for writing documents that is certainly the exception. Also when you review a paper are you given the tex source?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can do a lot with pdfs; check out some of the demos at the [TeX showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/#dynamics), including [this interactive, randomly generated math quiz](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/macqtexDemo.pdf), this [interactive periodic table](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/tabela_periodica.pdf), and [this animated Lorenz Attractor](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/LorenzAttractor.pdf).

Comment: @AndyW: No, typically authors only submit PDFs for review (so referees necessarily only get PDFs).  Many journals use the author's TeX source to prepare the camera-ready copy after the paper is accepted, but a few ask the author to do that, too.  Also, I don't know anyone in my field who doesn't write LaTeX source directly, without using a wizzywig editor.

Comment: @eykanal Thanks for sharing (I had never seen truly interactive in PDF before). Although I suspect the potential for interactivity in html is greater though. For one example, see some [Elsevier journals](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/intro.cws_home/googlemaps) related to spatial analysis now provide the ability to embed google maps in supplementary data. Wouldn't it be nice to have live applications in which you could pan and zoom graphics with tool tips for observations, or dynamic tables with publicly available data? I'm skeptical these things can be done in pdf (or only one file).

Comment: @JeffE, I can say the exact opposite for my field, in fact several of the journals in my field make you submit papers in WYSIWYG editor file formats! I use latex and wish others did as well, but to move the conversation forward I would say reliance on PDF's for *archiving research* is not a great solution.

Comment: @JeffE If my first paragraph after the binary/plain text note isn't clear I'm not quite sure what else I can say. PDF's aren't suitable for archives of data or research unless they are supplemented with material outside of the PDF, hence multiple file formats like I suggested. Reading the stuff who cares whether it is pdf or html webpage or printed paper or whatever, an archive of research and interactive collaboration takes more than just reading though.